# Fancybox não está abrindo como deveria

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou fazendo um cadastro em PHP utilizando fancybox, eu fiz a configuração da action para chamar a tela do javascript e o template que eu desejo utilizar. Porém dentro do html ao clicar no botão a fancybox está sendo direcionada para outra página ao invés de simplesmente abrir ali.

Página da Action:

```
class cadastroAction extends Action
{
    public function getResults()
    {
        return [
            SUCCESS => new TemplateResult(
                'templates/basico.php', [
                    'body' => 'views/cadastroLivros/titulo/form.php',
                    'js' => [
                        'js/livraria/cadastroLivros/titulo.js'
                    ]
                ]
            )
        ];
    }

    public function cadastrar(){

        return SUCCESS;

    }
}
```

Tela da fancybox:

```
<div class="portlet light border-0">
    <div class="portlet-title margin-botton-0">
        <div class="caption font-blue-steel">
            <i class="icon-trophy font-blue-steel"></i>
            <span class="caption-subject bold uppercase">Livros</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="portlet-body form">
        <form method="POST" id="form-livros" >
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label>Descrição</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>            
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Tela Javascript:

```
$('#btn-nova-inscricao').fancybox({
    titleShow: 'false',
    type : 'iframe',
    autoSize : false,
    width : '100%',
    height : '100%'
});
```

Código HTML:

```
<div id="main" class="portlet light margin-botton-0 paddingBottom0">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="portlet light portlet-fit">
                <div class="portlet-body">
                    <div id="livros" class="portlet light margin-botton-0 padding-lr-0">
                        <div class="portlet-title">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <i class="icon-trophy font-blue-steel"></i>
                                <span class="caption-subject font-blue-steel bold uppercase">Livros</span>
                                <span id="lblSubtituloTab" class="caption-helper">cadastro</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="actions">
                                <a id="btn-nova-inscricao" href="<?= ActionRequest::absurl("cadastroLivros", "cadastro", "cadastrar") ?>" class="btn btn-primary blue-steel pull-right"> Configurar Inscrição</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Obs: Sou iniciante e não estou conseguindo entender o que fiz de errado.

Comment: Coloca o código completo que envolva a questão. Por exemplo, onde está o botão clicado? Está usando AJAX?

Comment: Adicionado, é bem simples é só um botão chamando a action

Comment: está abrindo em qual página? nome

Comment: testa trocando: <?= ActionRequest::absurl("cadastroLivros", "cadastro", "cadastrar") ?> por views/cadastroLivros/titulo/form.php e veja se funciona. Eu ainda preciso do código da sua página inteira para conseguir te ajudar melhor

Comment: @LeandroAlfredo está abrindo em localhost/cadastroLivros/cadastro/cadastrar

Comment: consegue postar sua página inteira? Edite sua pergunta para eu entender melhor seu código

Comment: @LeandroAlfredo Esse é o código inteiro, eu apenas estou tentar aprender como funciona fancybox, fiz o javascript a action o html e a fancybox (modal) separada.

Comment: o fancybox funciona da seguinte maneira. Na mesma página vc precisa fazer os includes dos arquivos js do fancybox. Vc cria um link <a> com o href indo para a página que você queira mostrar no fancybox. No seu código type:iframe vc linka com o id tbm. basicamente é isto.

Comment: @LeandroAlfredo Uhuu eu consegui, quando você me falou para trocar o código notei que eu poderia tentar trocar usando url, então adicionei um código em jquery que ao clicar no botão e acionar a action ele chame a url através de um ajax, então adicionei ao invés de templateResult troquei por BasicResult. Agora deu certo. Obrigado!

Comment: @LeandroAlfredo Isso eu estava esquecendo de linkar o ID agora que linkei o ID usando o ajax deu certo =D

Comment: @GustavoMazzo show